# Introducing flask_socketio to work with a simple already made flask application

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm new to both Flask and `flask-socketio`.

I first made the tutorial app from Flask official [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/).

And I follow [this](https://codeburst.io/building-your-first-chat-application-using-flask-in-7-minutes-f98de4adfa5d) to make a simple chat app using `flask-socketio`.

What I need is the authentication system from Flask tutorial and the simple chat feature from the SocketIO tutorial.

The Flask tutorial runs the Flask app inside the `create_app` method in `__init__.py`.

**__init__.py**:

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )
    # ...
    
    return app
```

The SocketiIO tutorial have only a `main.py` file that runs the SocketIO application.

**main.py**:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')

# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

I've been read a lot of questions about integrating `flask-socketio` with already made Flask application, but all of them try to integrate using a `main.py` file that you can put `socketio.run()` method to run inside the `if __name__`.

Is it possible to run both http server with socket server in the same app initializing the app from `create_app` method?

Answer (score 0):

For people that reach this question, the creator of the package teaches how to deal with this issue [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/362#issuecomment-879910494).

```
socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )
    # ...

    socketio.init_app(app)

    return app
```

It's just a matter of creating a global SocketIO object and starting after in `creat_app`.